# Calculate text similarity between lists using CountVectorizer, TFIDFVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, countvectorizer, tfidfvectorizer

I would like to see similarity between lists using `TFIDFVectorizer` and `CountVectorizer`.

I have lists like below:

```py
list1 = [['i','love','machine','learning','its','awesome'],
         ['i', 'love', 'coding', 'in', 'python'],
         ['i', 'love', 'building', 'chatbots']]
list2 = ['i', 'love', 'chatbots']
```

I would like to see similarity between `list1[0]` and `list2`, `list1[1]` and `list2` , `list1[2]` and `list2`.

Expecting output should be like `[0.99 , 0.67, 0.54]`

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) `TfidfVectorizer` is:
*"Equivalent to CountVectorizer followed by TfidfTransformer."*

Here is the code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

corpus = [
    "i love machine learning its awesome",
    "i love coding in python",
    "i love building chatbots",
    "i love chatbots"
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
# print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
arr = X.toarray()
```

And the answers using **cosine similarity**

```
# similarity of yours `list1[0] and list2`  
np.dot(arr[0], arr[3]) # gives ~0.139
# similarity of yours `list1[1] and list2`  
np.dot(arr[1], arr[3]) # gives ~0.159
# similarity of yours `list1[2] and list2`  
np.dot(arr[2], arr[3]) # gives ~0.687
```

or using **jaccard similarity** and `CountVectorizer` I think is closer to what you are expecting

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
arr = X.toarray()

jaccard_score(arr[0], arr[3]) # gives 0.5
jaccard_score(arr[1], arr[3]) # gives 0.6
jaccard_score(arr[2], arr[3]) # gives 0.9
```